# Requirements or limits for tiling a huge number of TIFFs

Tags: gdalwarp, gdal2tiles, gdalbuildvrt

I want to create webtiles from the topographic maps of large areas, eg. a whole country. So I have some 100 GeoTIFFs, all 4000x4000.

So first I create a vrt:

```
gdalbuildvrt tifs.vrt tifs/*.tif
```

Second is reprojection to Mercator:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 -r lanczos tifs.vrt  mercator.tif
```

This will result in a huge reprojected TIFF, containing all the joined tifs.

As last step the tiling:

```
gdal2tiles -w leaflet -a 0.0  -z 1-13  mercator.tif tiles.webtiles
```

I tried this with the 1:200.000 scale tiffs resulting in a intermediate mercator.tif of 35000x40000 pixel and it worked well. The final webtiles are fine.

Before I go on now with the 1:25.000, which is 260 single TIFFs, I would like to ask, if there are any limits, because the intermediate mercator.tif will be huge now. Will 32GB ram on my MacBook Pro and 1TB free space on drive be enough? Of course it will take a while.

Comment: Avoid this way if possible. Nearly no one is pregenerating on a single machine tiles for a large coverage as it can take ages. They serve image using a tile server or they distribute data processing on multiple machines in the cloud by generating tiles for only a part of the big coverage and then at the end, gather each generated tiles subpart on one place from each machine.

Comment: You may calculate approximate total tiles size for levels and a particular area (calculation for a "classic" map, not imagery) https://tools.geofabrik.de/calc/#type=geofabrik_standard&bbox=-5.492211,41.329342,10.009743,51.67531 to evaluate if worth trying it

Comment: at least tile and compress the intermediate tif

Comment: I think you can skip the gdalwarp step and run directly `gdal2tiles -w leaflet -a 0.0  -z 1-13  tifs.vrt tiles.webtiles`.